# CALayer is not showing on Device

Tags: ios, core-animation, calayer, cabasicanimation

I have a custom layer (which is subclass of CALayer). In that class I override the methods `needsDisplayForKey:`, `initWithLayer:`, `actionForKey:`, like this:

```
-(id<CAAction>)actionForKey:(NSString *)event 
{
    if ([event isEqualToString:@"duration"]) {
        return [self animationForKey:event];
    }  
    return [super actionForKey:event];
}

- (CABasicAnimation *)animationForKey:(NSString *)key
{
    NSString *animValue = [[self presentationLayer] valueForKey:key];
    CABasicAnimation *anim;

    if([key isEqualToString:@"duration"]) {
        anim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
        anim.repeatCount = HUGE_VAL;
        anim.autoreverses = YES;
        anim.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.5f];       
    }
    anim.duration = 2;    
    return anim;
}
```

I used this CALayer as follows

```
@property(strong,nonatomic)ArcLayer *arcLayer;

self.arcLayer=[ArcLayer layer];;
self.arcLayer.duration=2;
self.arcLayer.frame = self.bounds;
self.arcLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor].CGColor;
[self.layer addSublayer:self.arcLayer];
```

This code works fine on the simulator where it shows the ArcLayer with animation. However, the ArcLayer is not showing on the device.

Why it is not working on the device?

Comment: Is that all the code there is? What do you mean by "is not showing"? Not at all?

Comment: Yes not showing at all on Device,But It is showing in simulator

Comment: Where are you creating this layer? How does it behave without the animation?

Comment: I am creating this layer in UIView subclass.ArcLayer is not showing without animation